# c# tell Visual Studio that property is not null after method call

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, nullable-reference-types

How can I tell Visual Studio IntelliSense that property of property is not null after calling its method

Inner class:

```
class Inner
{
    int? Property { get; set; }

    [MemberNotNull(nameof(Property))]
    void Initialize
    {
        Property = 42;
    }
}
```

Caller class:

```
class Caller
{
    // We know here that constructor is always called before other methods
    public Caller()
    {
        InnerObj = new Inner();

        // We know here that InnerObj.Property is always not null
        InnerObj.Initialize();
    }

    public Inner InnerObj { get; }

    public void MethodWithNullWarning()
    {
        // Null Warning
        InnerObj.Property.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all it would be great to provide compilable code =)

Comment: Also I can't repro the warning - [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQcAMACOSB0AIgJYCGA5lAPYDOwxAxjfgMJUAmApgIJSkA2ATxrEaAbnQBiKBH79SAI36dsnPks7p0eAJwAKKJwDu2FgOVg9ASnwBJKIbAB5BQCt8ABTBUADpzDAgvgAKlQAysBgxFDk1lYSGAjY9o7oAN7o2Fm4AMzY0cAA/Nhevv6B2GnY5JzAYtg0tfUAvlpo2dgA2gCynAC2Cv4AclTAQ7L8BqR9nFQAZnqlfgGCVlYAupnZcHlwACzJUMT0AsQAXpzWW1kZ7R3ZS+WC2AC82HsICR2taD/aSWY5P50tdsKCdqZzP4rncbqCOil/C5XK9sIYTIjLPF4dlMci7EcTvxzpdsbDsH9yRDMYdHMjKtUmhS2h0IftsL1gAALDgAdWOXPGcl5pDARxiMI6t3uuIcSLcnm8y0CIXCkWisTJ33QzSAA=)

Comment: @GuruStron Property needs to be a reference type to reproduce this.

Comment: @tymtam nullability analysis works for nullable value types also)

Comment: @GuruStron For `int? x = null;` the `x` is not null. `Console.WriteLine(x.HasValue);` is OK. `InnerObj.Property.Value.ToString();` would produce the warning.

Comment: @tymtam yes, but `Console.WriteLine(x.Value);` will produce the warning (in nullable enabled context). As changing `ToString` to `GetType`: `InnerObj.Property.GetType();` in OP's question. The problem here is not to guess what will produce the warning, but that OP code does not even compile and when fixed to be compilable  does not reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning the property in the constructor doesn't guarantee it will not be null.

Let's add the following method:

```
public void MakeItNull() { InnerObj.Property = null; }
```

Then:

```
Caller caller = new ();

caller.MakeItNull();
caller.MethodWithNullWarning();
```

Boom!

---

### Solutions

Here are some options.

#### 1. !

[! (null-forgiving) operator (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving)

```
InnerObj.Property!.ToString();
```

Please note that this doesn't protect from a null reference exception if the value is actually null.

#### 2. Have a constructor

```
class Inner
{
    public string Property { get; set; } // string, not string!

    public Inner() {
        Property = "42";
    }
}
```

#### 3. Use a different property for external access.

```
class Inner
{
    private string? RealProperty { get; set; }


    public string Property => RealProperty!;

    public void Initialize() {
        RealProperty = "42";
    }
}
```

Comment: You has just opened my eyes. Thanks for MakeItNull example)